# JS Content Generation Prolem

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, class

**Introduction( kind of :) )**

First of all I **generate 5 coffee** beans for one coffee. The coffee class has the attribute strength and i want to **grey out** the coffee beans which are **> strength** (Like in the picture below).

[image]

**My CoffeeMachine Class (simplified):**

```
class CoffeeMachine {
    constructor() {
        this.name = ""
        this.coffeeList = { list: [] }
        this.tokenList = { list: [] }
        this.shoppingCard = { list: [] }
    }
    addCoffe(coffee) {
        this.coffeeList.list.push(coffee)
    }
    addToken(token) {
        this.coffeeList.list.push(token)
    }
    addToCart(item) {
        this.shoppingCard.list.push(item)
    }
}
```

**My Coffee Class (simplified):**

```
class Coffee {
    constructor() {
        this.name = ""
        this.price = 0
        this.time = 0.0
        this.imgsrc = ""
        this.strength = 0
        this.sugar = 0
        this.caffeine = 0
        this.values = []
        this.titelArray = ["caffeeine", "sugar", "time", "strength"]
        this.colors = ["#e34444", "#7944e3", "#44e35c", "#e3d044"]
    }
    setValues(name, price, time, strength, imgsrc, sugar, caffeine) {
        this.name = name
        this.price = price
        this.time = time
        this.strength = strength
        this.imgsrc = imgsrc
        this.sugar = sugar
        this.caffeine = caffeine
    }
    setCoffeeValues() {
        this.values = [this.caffeine + "mg", this.sugar + "g", this.time + "s", this.strength + "/5"]
    }

}
```

The coffees will be pushed into the shopping cart list in the coffee machine like below:

```
coffeeMachine.shoppingCard.list.push(coffeeMachine.coffeeList.list[index])
```

**Init the coffees**

```
coffeeLatte.setValues("Latte Macchiato", 1.60, 30.0, 3, "../pics/coffeeLatte.png", 18, 75)
        coffeeBlack.setValues("Black Coffee", 1.20, 20.0, 5, "../pics/coffeeBlack.png", 4, 95)
        coffeCappunchino.setValues("Cappuccino", 1.60, 35, 2, "../pics/coffeeCappuchino.png", 12, 64)
```

**The update shopping cart method in the coffee machine class (the prolem):**

This is how I generate the beans for each coffee in the list:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < this.shoppingCard.list.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('beans')[i].innerHTML += `<img class="bean" src="../pics/bean.png"></img>`
            }
        }
```

In the code below I set the opacity to 100% for the one <= coffee.strengtha and the opacity for the others to 30%:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.shoppingCard.list.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < this.shoppingCard.list[i].strength; j++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('bean')[i].style.opacity = "1"
        if (j <= this.shoppingCard.list[i].strength){
            for (let k = this.shoppingCard.list[i].strength; k < 5; k++) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('bean')[k].style.opacity = "0.3"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding a few coffes to the shopping cart this happens:
[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is?

Comment: the coffee beans which are > [coffee strength] do not get greyed out. every bean has opacity 100%.

Comment: the part under this "headline" "In the code below I set the opacity to 100% for the one <= coffee.strengtha and the opacity for the others to 30%:" don't work

Comment: Okay, could you make a [working snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548) of the (minimal) amount of code required to reproduce your problem? Breaking your JS into several paragraphs, and without any of the requisite HTML (or CSS), makes it harder than necessary for us to recreate your problem, or post meaningful answers.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]; you can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I'll try to reduce the code to the minimum in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be a solution for you problem

```
for (let j = 1; j <= this.shoppingCard.list[i]; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        if (k + 1 < this.shoppingCard.list[i].strength) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('bean')[0].children[k].style.opacity = "1"
        } else {
            document.getElementsByClassName('bean')[0].children[k].style.opacity = "0.3"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what all the loops are for, give this a try:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.shoppingCard.list.length; i++) {
  let strength = this.shoppingCard.list[i].strength;
  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('bean')[i * 5 + j].style.opacity = j <= strength ? "1" : "0.3";
  }
}
```

Comment: the first loop is for the iteration through the list. the second: to give them an opacity value. the third loop is for "greying out" the rest of the beans.

Comment: didn't worked. same problem as before. every bean gets an 100% opacity.

Comment: I put `i <= strength` instead of `j <= strength` - any better?